# Roblox: How do I check with an if statement which team the player is on?

Tags: roblox

I want to check with an if statement which team the player is currently on.

Thank you for advance,

Jesse

Comment: https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/property/Player/Team

Comment: @Mareks Zirdins This is not where I asked for. I asked to check in the if statement if the player is in that team then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry but this is canceled cause I found an alternative.

Best regards and sorry,

Jesse

Comment: If you find an answer to a question, it never hurts to post your answer, even if it is an alternative solution. Someone else probably has the same question.